# ASP.NET MVC input value is not passed to controller action when value changed via jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, devexpress-mvc

I have a DevExpress SpinEdit amount field:

[image: SpinEdit Field]

```
 @Html.DevExpress().SpinEditFor(model => model.Tare, settings =>
                                {
                                    settings.Width = 153;
                                    settings.Properties.DisplayFormatString = @"0.0,0";
                                }).GetHtml()
```

When I change the value manually the value is passed correctly to the controller.

[image: Model Value When Manually]

But when I change the value via jquery it is displayed correctly but is not passed to the controller.

```
var gross = parseFloat($('#Brutto_Raw').val().replace(',', '.'));
var net = parseFloat($('#Amount_Raw').val().replace(',', '.'));
var tare = gross - net;
$('#Tare_I').val(parseFloat(tare).toPrecision(12));    
$('#Tare_Raw').val(parseFloat(tare).toPrecision(12));
```

[image: Display Value Changed Via Jquery]

[image: Model Value When Changed Via Jquery]

Comment: View the DOM while the page is active (e.g. the Chrome F12 tools) and see if the SpinEditFor is changing the structure of the elements. Plugins often add extra elements and sometimes even hide the original input field.

Comment: Try to use DevExpress own client side API

Comment: Like ``Tare_i.setValue ("valuehere");``

Comment: Thank you. You are both right. It works now using the client side API.